# Keeping ASP.NET Session / Forms Authentication Alive in Silverlight application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have a web app containing a silverlight application.

How do I keep the ASP.NET session / Forms Authentication alive when the user is using the silverlight application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By periodically pinging it with an HttpRequest.